# using getopt to parse command line arguments

Tags: c, getopt

I'm trying to use getopt to parse my command line arguments but i'm having an issue where it is setting the wrong values its skipping case 1 and setting case 2 as case 1.Here is the while loop of just the cases. The flags work fine its just reading in by position that is the problem.

```
while ((c = getopt (argc, argv, "-l:u:eo")) != -1)
         switch (c)
           {
           case 1:
            printf("here\n");
             lower = atoi(optarg);
             break;
           case 2:
             upper = atoi(optarg);
             break;
    }
```

here is the output from the terminal after running the program.

```
(%) fibon 12 22
here
here
lower = 22, upper = 0, even = 0, odd = 0
Usage: fibon[[lower upper] | [-l lower -u upper]] [-e|-o]
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [`getopt(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html) manual page:

> If the first character of `optstring` is `'-'`, then each nonoption `argv`-element is handled as if it were the argument of an option with character code `1`.

That means that *both* numbers will be returned from `getopt` as `1`. You need to keep track of which option you have yourself.

Comment: can you clarify more i don't understand how to keep track of the options

Comment: @user3400512 Keep a counter, initialized to `1`. If it's `1` its the first value and you increase the counter. If it's `2` it's the second value. Etc.

Comment: i tried doing the counter and when counter is 1 lower = atoi(argv[1]) and increment the counter and do the same for when counter is 2 but it still isn't working.